# How to check if a point is within a convex hull?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, computational-geometry, convex-hulls, decision-problems

**BACKGROUND**

I'm working on a physics problem whereby I want to check whether a vector $\vec{v}$ of $D \in \mathbb{N}$ measurements $v_d \in [-1, 1]$, $d \in \{1, \cdots, D\}$ can result from the statistical averaging of $K \in \mathbb{N}$ possible measurement outcomes $\vec{w}^{(k)}$, $k \in \{1, \cdots, K \}$ where $w_d^{(k)} \in \{-1, 1\}$. (Note that unlike the elements of $\vec{v}$, those of $\vec{w}^{(k)}$ can only be $\pm 1$).

In other words, I want to check whether there exists a probability distribution $\vec{p}$ of dimension $K$ such that the following three conditions are satisfied, namely

$
\begin{equation}
v_d = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{K} p_k w^{(k)}_d,
\end{equation}
$
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{k} p_k = 1$, and $p_k \in [0, 1]$.

This is therefore an overcomplete problem if $K > D$, and, if I understand correctly, boils down to finding whether $\vec{v}$ lies within the convex hull formed by $\{\vec{w}^{(k)}\}\mid_{k=1}^K$.

**QUESTION**

How does one resolve the problem above, both analytically and algorithmically? Also, if it turns out that $\vec{v}$ can't be explained as a statistical mixture of $\vec{w}^{(k)}$'s, then can we quantify how far it is from being so, i.e., presumably, how far it lies from the convex hull?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check containment of convex hull we usually have to compute the convex hull and then decide whether the new point is actually within this convex hull.

While there are [many algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms#Algorithms) to compute the convex hull, checking the containment of a point within a convex hull is usually done using [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) solver. (also see that it is roughly equivalent [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11508/deciding-membership-in-a-convex-hull)).

To actually do this in practice I recommend relying on existing software (as understanding these algorithms and implementing them *efficiently* takes a lot of time). For example [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html) has an arbitrary dimension convex hull algorithm built in, and requires  only [a few lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750618/whats-an-efficient-way-to-find-if-a-point-lies-in-the-convex-hull-of-a-point-cl).

The only point that I see that might make your problem a little bit easier is the fact that your $w^{(k)}$ are the vertices of some hyper cube. (So a simple thing to do would first be checking whether $v \in [-1,1]^D$ so you can avoid doing the more expensive computations.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that SciPy code, but can it actually return the combination $\vec{p}$ or does it just say whether $\vec{v}$ falls within the hull? Could it also return the shortest distance between the hull and $\vec{v}$?

Comment: You probably need some additional lines of code to get the combination, probably using a linear programming method. But you can directly infer whether it is inside the hull (see the link to SO) and the distance to the boundary is just a matter of iterating over all the faces of the convex hull and finding the minimal distance.

Comment: I played around with the code. I tried a certain value of $\vec{v}$ which the `in_hull()` function said to be inside the hull. I then tried a least square fit to compute $\vec{p}$ using NumPy. Half the elements of $\vec{p}$ turned out to be negative, which means they can't be interpreted as probabilities. So now I'm confused about the very definition of a convex hull. How can the coefficients be negative and yet the function says that it's inside the hull?

Comment: As the system is underdetermined a least squares fit will not necessarily find a valid solution to your problem as they usually try to minimize the norm of the solution in this case. You'd need a linear programming solver that let you include the constraints.

Comment: Earlier you said that the distance between the hull and $\vec{v}$ is just a matter of iterating over the faces of the hull and finding the minimum distance. Can one alternatively perform a constrained fitting of the parameters $\vec{p}$ and then take the Euclidean distance between the fitted $W \vec{p}$ and  $\vec{v}$ (where $W$ is assembled from the $\vec{w}_k$s)?

Comment: @Tfovid I just noticed I misunderstood your question regarding the distance: My proposed solution only works to compute the distance of $v$ to the convex hull if $v$ is *inside* the convex hull. Regarding your suggestion: That depends  little bit on how you optimize for $p$. If try to optimize the euclidean distance between $Wp$ and $v$ (that is minimizing $\Vert Wp v \Vert_2$ under the constraints), then you will indeed find the (euclidean) distance, but if you use some other optimization objective then this might not necessarily be the case.

Comment: Actually, the optimization objective I used is to minimize $\sqrt{\mid\mid W\vec{p} - \vec{v}\mid\mid}$, not $\sqrt{\mid\mid W\vec{p}\vec{v}\mid\mid}$, unless you were referring to maximizing the latter.

Comment: Sorry yes that is a typo, I must have forgotten the `-`.