# Generate cycle graph from vertices

Tags: computational-geometry, convex-hulls

I have `K` vertices and I need to connect them to form a graph. I am currently generating a complete undirected graph that looks like these:

[image: complete graphs]

However, I only need the exterior edges, the edges that would make up the perimeter. That would be the red edges below. Any other edges on the inside I can remove.

[image]

I'm searching for an algorithm that will help me generate just the outside edges, or an algorithm that will let me detect the outside edges so that I can remove them. I've looked into things like edge coloring, edge contraction, and even generating cycle graphs, but none of them seem to do what I want. I think part of the issue is my lack of terminology so searching isn't giving me great results.

Is there an algorithm given `K` vertices that I can form a graph of just the exterior edges?

Comment: What do you mean by "generating"? How are you representing your graphs?

Comment: I suppose as just a list of vertices. But currently they can be in any order. I need or sort them so they form either a clockwise or counter-clockwise loop of the perimeter.

Comment: What do you mean just a list of vertices? Graphs don't have a "perimeter". Are you familiar with the definition of a graph?

Comment: Yes. However like I said there could be some terminology lacking here. If you know a better word to explain this please let me know. I want to connect `K` vertices and end up with only exterior edges.

Comment: Well just take the graph with $V(G)=\{1,\dots, k\}$ and $E(G) = \{12, 23, 34, \dots, (k-1)k, k1\}$, i.e., the [cycle graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph).

Comment: There is no such thing as "interior" / "exterior" edges, since that is just a property of the embedding. Indeed, on 5 vertices, the red/blue graph you illustrated are actually the same. (In other words, the red cycle on it's own and the blue star shape on its own are actually the exact same graph, since the blue graph is also a 5 cycle).

Comment: Is there a way to get a list of edges for the cycle graph given a list of vertices? I looked at the algorithm [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28graph_theory%29#Algorithm) but that will generate a list of all cycles, I would still need to filter out the cycle that is just made up of the exterior edges somehow.

Comment: I understand the red/blue cycles are the same graph, but I'm struggling to see how I can isolate the two or differentiate the red vs blue cycles.

Comment: You need to know the vertices and edges in your graph. What graph are you starting from? That algorithm tries to find cycles in a given graph. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: The only data I have is `K` vertices (x,y,z). I'm trying to figure out the perimeter those vertices make when they are connected together with edges. The problem I ran into is how do I know which vertices to connect? If I connect every vertex with every other vertex, I end up with the complete graph. Instead I just need the outside edges so I can form a polygon with each vertex being a point on the polygon edge. Once I have the polygon I can do other things like getting the centroid, the axis of symmetry, and more, but I just need to take the vertices and turn them into a perimeter.

Comment: Are these vertices coordinates in space?

Comment: Yes, they are 3D coordinates. I'm projecting them down to 2D so really only the X and Y matter for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Finally this makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a geometric problem. You have a finite set of points $S\subseteq \mathbb R^n$, and you want to determine the edges which bound the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of $S$ (since this is a polytope).

First, you need to determine which of the points in $S$ are actually vertices on the boundary—there are many algorithms to do this, known as [convex hull algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms), such as [Quickhull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickhull).

Once you have the set $B\subseteq S$ of boundary points of the convex hull, you can find the edges by considering each pair of points $P,Q\in B$ (there are $\binom{|B|}2$ such pairs) and use [linear programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3206677/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-within-a-convex-hull) to check whether the midpoint $(P+Q)/2$ is in the convex hull of the $|B|-2$ remaining points.

---

This is more of a geometry thing rather than a graph theory thing. In graph theory we usually don't care about the position of the points.

Comment: Thanks, I got this working as expected. Sorry for the confusing start. This was helpful!

Comment: @anon Glad to be of help.